# Function callback handler unable to pass the full float array from CLI/C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, callback, c++-cli

I have to pass a float array as a parameter of a function callback handler. The float array(image data) will be generated in C++ side, and C# code can receive the array. My current code only pass the first element `array[0]` to the C#.

I declared the handler in c++ code like this

```
class ArrayHandler { 
    public:

    typedef void(*ImageHandler) (float *img, int size, char *msg);

    ArrayHandler();
    ~ArrayHandler();

    void Hello(ImageHandler);

private:
    ImageHandler m_imgHandler;
};
```

The implementation of member function `Hello(ImageHandler)` is

```
void ArrayHandler::Hello(ImageHandler h)
{
    m_imgHandler = h;
    int size = 5;
    char *msg = "Hello";
    float arry[5] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    m_imgHandler(arry, 5, msg);
}
```

In CLI/C++ wrapper, I declare the `ImageHandler` as

```
delegate void ImageHandler(cli::array<float>^ img, int size, String ^msg);
```

The implementation of `Hello(ImageHandler ^ih)` in wrapper is

```
void WrappedHandler::Wrapped::Hello(ImageHandler ^ih)
{
    wrapped_ImageHandler = ih;
    IntPtr ip = 
    Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(wrapped_ImageHandler);

    ArrayHandler::ImageHandler nativeHandler = 
    reinterpret_cast<ArrayHandler::ImageHandler>(ip.ToPointer());

    m_ArrayHandler->Hello(nativeHandler);
}
```

I use the following to call the function in C#.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Wrapped test = new Wrapped();
        test.Hello(ImageFromHandler);
    }

    private static void ImageFromHandler(float[] img, int size, string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
        int l = img.Length;
        if(l != size){
            Console.WriteLine("Size not match");
        }
    }
}
```

I run the program, and I found the size of float array passed to C# is 1, and only the first element is passed. Then I tried something not intuitive such as passing a array of float array, but the program break for some reasons. I think the problem may occur when I marshal the handler to native pointer. I'm also confused that the string type parameter which is declared as `char *` in c++ is able to be passed, but the `float *` failed.

Thanks.

Comment: That's because the .NET marshaler can't know that the `size` parameter is the size of the `img` array unless you tell it so. Just put an attribute on `img`: `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)]`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thanks!  That's exactly what is missing. I will do more research about .NET marshaler, and figure out all these parameters.

Comment: It would have been much easier to just copy the data yourself, into a true .NET array (and back again after the call if the function is intended to write to the array).  `reinterpret_cast` on a function pointer is almost always undefined behavior.